# With flex box, setting canvas's width and height with parent node's clientWidth and Height hides sticky footer

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, flexbox

I'm trying to create column layout below, i.e. header, content and sticky footer. 
And I want canvas's width and height to follow its content's clientWidth and clientHeight using JavaScript.

```
<style>
body {
;   margin          : 0
;   height          : 100%
;   display         : flex
;   flex-direction  : column
}

header,
footer {
;   flex    : 0
}

#content {
;   flex    : 1
}
</style>

<header>header</header>
<div id=content>
    <canvas id=canvas></canvas>
</div>
<footer>footer</footer>

<script>
    canvas = document.getElementById( 'canvas' )
    ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' )
    const
    FitCanvas = () => {
        canvas.width = canvas.parentNode.clientWidth
        canvas.height = canvas.parentNode.clientHeight
        ctx.beginPath()
        ctx.moveTo( 0, 0 )
        ctx.lineTo( canvas.width, canvas.height )
        ctx.stroke()
    }
    window.addEventListener(
        'resize'
    ,   FitCanvas
    )
    FitCanvas()
</script>
```

It seems good when expanding window. But when shrinking window, the footer doesn't stick.

Initial:
[image: Initial]

Expanded:
[image: Expanded]

Shrinked:
[image: Shrinked]

I want make Shrinked image to match Initial image.

Please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you expand your viewport, `FitCanvas` makes the canvas bigger which makes `<div id=content>` bigger. When you shrink the viewport, `<div id=content>` keeps a size to fit its children, i.e. the `canvas`.

You should rewrite your `FitCanvas` function not to base its calculation on the parent's size.

```js
canvas.width = canvas.parentNode.clientWidth
canvas.height = canvas.parentNode.clientHeight
```

should become something along the lines of

```js
canvas.width = window.innerWidth
canvas.height = window.innerHeight - header.offsetHeight - footer.offsetHeight
```

This is not the most efficient way of doing things but hopefully it points you in the right direction and you see why the `'resize'` handler seemed to work only one way.

Comment: Thanks, it's perfect answer.